# How to calculate upper bound and lower bound in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

How to calculate upper bound and lower bound in Angular?

```
  yearClassColumns(yearClassCount: number) {
     return yearClassCount > 10
      ? yearClassCount / 2 + (yearClassCount % 2)
      : yearClassCount;
    }



  setCustomerColumns(numberOfYear: number) {
     return this.yearClassColumns(numberOfYear);
     }
```

**I want to return the upper limit value**

I tried,

```
this.numOfColumns = Math.trunc(this.yearClassColumns(numberOfYear));
```

Comment: Please refine the question, what is the sample data, I understand you want max and min, we can use `Math.max` and `Math.min`, please provide all the details!

Comment: upper bound and lower bound of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
setCustomerColumns(numberOfYear: number) {
  const upper = Math.ceil(this.yearClassColumns(numberOfYear)); return upper;
}
```